# if condition for join query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

```
SELECT tm.MAGAZINE_ID, tm.publisher_id, tu.begin_date, tu.report_from,
units `MAGAZINE_NAME`
FROM `tbl_itunes_report` tu 
LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine_subscription_dtl tsd 
  ON tsd.subscription_key = tu.sku_key 
  AND ((tu.begin_date >= tsd.start_date 
  AND tu.begin_date < tsd.end_date) OR (tu.begin_date >= tsd.start_date 
  AND tsd.end_date = '0000-00-00')) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine_subscription ts 
  ON ts.magazine_subscription_id = tsd.subs_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine_issue ti 
  ON ti.PurchaseKey = tu.sku_key AND ti.OS_SELECT = 0 
LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine tm 
  ON tm.magazine_id = ts.magazine_id OR tm.magazine_id =  ti.magazine_id 
WHERE `product_type_identifier` LIKE 'IA%' 
  AND ( tsd.subscription_key IS NOT NULL OR ti.PurchaseKey IS NOT NULL ) 
GROUP BY tm.MAGAZINE_ID,tsd.no_of_issues 
ORDER BY tm.magazine_name, tsd.no_of_issues
```

Using this query I will generate my report. There are 4 joins in it.
In the case `tbl_magazine_subscription_dtl`, `tbl_magazine_issue` uses the `sku_key` field for joining. The `sku_key` value is present in only one table at a time, but the joining will lead to decreased query speed. Is it possible to check if `sku_key` is present or not before the join is performed?

Comment: Are both tables indexed on sku_key? I don't believe the join should decrease performance as first checking which table contains sku_key is equally time consuming

Comment: tbl_magazine_subscription_dtl - tbl_magazine_issue are time consuming.

Comment: because only one had sku_key equivalence present then it take all data from the table. if it possible sku_key present in corresponded table before it joining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, do you want only the rows where `sku_key` is not null and present in both `tbl_magazine_issue` and `tbl_magazine_subscription_dtl`? In that case, you should do an inner join instead of a left outer join on `tbl_magazine_issue`, and add a `AND tu.sku_key IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clause. The query engine should be smart enough to apply this condition before the join.

You should also make sure that `sku_key` and `PurchaseKey` are indexed if you're concerned about performance of this join.

Comment: i want magazine_id, publisher id. This details present in tbl_magazine. But linking to this table i want to join 
    tbl_magazine_subscription or tbl_magazine_issue because this table contain sku_key. Sku key related with subscription if the record is subscribed then the sku is with tbl_magazine_subscription other wise tbl_magazine_issue. one sku_key is related with one table at a time. so one of the joining is useless. so i want to avoid this joining